# how to make font-awesome icon in button clickable?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I have a icon in a button. When I click the button (literally rest of the area of the button except the icon), the button will show a drop down list under it. However, when I click the down arrow icon in the button, the drop down list doesn't show up. I need to make sure both button and icon are clickable. How do I do that?

Here is the code snippet:

```js
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}
    
// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```css
#myDropdown {
  display: none;
}
#myDropdown.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="btn dropbtn btn-primary">
        More <i style='font-size:16px' title='More' class='fas'>&#xf0d7;</i>
    </button>

    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content" style="line-height:15px;">                
        <a href="#" target="_blank">Duplicate New</a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">Download PDF</a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">Print PDF</a>        
        <a href="#" class="delete" data-id="{{ $dataTypeContent->getKey() }}" id="delete-{{ $dataTypeContent->getKey() }}">Delete</a>        
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's working fine on mobile devices.

Answer (score 1):

The `window.onclick` function should also be triggered when you click either on the `<button>` or `<i>`, but since the `event.target` is not `dropbtn` when you click on the `<i>` it's most likely passing the `if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn'))` check and closing the dropdown like it would if you clicked elsewhere on the screen.

I'd try `if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn') && !event.target.matches('.fas'))` to see if that fixes it. If so, I'd add a more specific class to the `<i>` such as `dropdown-toggle` and check if it matches that, otherwise it wouldn't close the dropdown if you click any other font-awesome icon on the screen.

**Update** - looks like that did it, here is the JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/p1kw746q/

Comment: Or you can type it as `!event.target.matches('.dropbtn, .dropbtn *')` to simplify so it will check whether it's `dropbtn` which trigger the event, or everything inside `dropbtn` if there's any other elements